# Why is TAB Key not working to cycle into Edit Mode?

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

Using Blender 2.79a, Usually I cannot get into edit mode using the Tab key *the first time* I go to use it with *any* object, but after I click the "Edit Object Button" I can usually cycle back and forth from Object Mode to Edit Mode using the Tab key.

*Notes:*

1. *When hitting the Tab key. Nothing happens.*
2. *This is the same with all blend files.*
3. *I have set up custom key shortcuts, but to my knowledge have not change anything to do with Edit or Object mode.*

Why does this only happen sometimes? I have ruled out having anything under my tab key that would cause this issue.

Has anyone else run into this problem? Or do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Reset the keyboard to the default settings

Answer (score 2):

Solved

It's not enough to just restore your key config, you have to reset it, much like cegaton said.

Go to the Input panel. Hover the "Add or Remove Key-config Preset" dropdown box, and click on "Blender". Then Save User Settings

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts:

- Test another version of Blender (especially, stable ones of course)
- Check if the key works reliable in other programs
- If you have some special keyboard: Force your OS to use the plug and play driver

  - And check your driver settings itself: Some day my headphones were incredibly quiet. After weeks, i found that I've changed the volume of a specific program INSIDE the driver. So the OS had no clue... Similar things may have happend to your keyboard layout.
- Ultimately, try another keyboard. If you don't have one, OS'es these days should have an on-screen keyboard available somewhere.

Comment: The tab key works for objects I've already went into edit mode with, but not on new objects. Also, I've restored my key config settings, but to no avail.

Comment: I should add, I've tried reinstalling 2.79a and also installed 2.8, but the results are the same. Thank you for your suggestions.